# Aggregate rows of same Date with the same Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe like that :

```
    Date            Tic      CLose
0   01/03/2022      AAPL     34.08
1   01/03/2022      HD       22.05
2   02/03/2022      AAPL     39.43
3   02/03/2022      HD       55.45
```

and I'd like to make rows with the same date to have the same index number like that :

Desired Output :

```
    Date            Tic      CLose
0   01/03/2022      AAPL     34.08
0   01/03/2022      HD       22.05
1   02/03/2022      AAPL     39.43
1   02/03/2022      HD       55.45
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's do `factorize` to encode the `Date` values then update the index:

```
df.index = df['Date'].factorize(sort=True)[0]
```

---

```
         Date   Tic  CLose
0  01/03/2022  AAPL  34.08
0  01/03/2022    HD  22.05
1  02/03/2022  AAPL  39.43
1  02/03/2022    HD  55.45
```